# Android erro getIntent

Tags: android, intent, android-activity

Olá,

Tenho uma aplicação que preciso enviar dados de uma `Activity` para outra `Activity`. Testei de diversas maneiras no entanto todas falharam, mas em um outro projeto um código funcionava normalmente, mas em meu atual não. Pode ser um erro de lógica ou de sequência dos códigos? Preciso enviar o valor de `Byte` 1 ou 2, da `Activity Main` para a `DemE`. Segue abaixo o código.

**ActivityMain**:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Byte valor = 1;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, DemE.class);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putByte("dado", valor);
    intent.putExtras(params);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**ActivityDemE**:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle params = intent.getExtras();

Byte valor = params.getByte("dado");
Toast.makeText(DemE.this, "valor" + valor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Utilizei o `Toast` para testar se os valores estavam sendo recebidos, porém o valor era retornado como `null`.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa colocar um `Bundle` como extra de sua `Intent`, já que, o extra da sua `Intent` já é um `Bundle` ([de acordo com a documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras())).

Então, você simplesmente precisa fazer o seguinte:

```
...
Byte valor = 1;
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, DemE.class);
intent.putExtras("valor", valor);
startActivity(intent);
...
```

Para recuperar este valor, você pode:

1) Colocar dentro de um Bundle como já está fazendo (isso é vantajoso caso você tenha vários objetos dentro de um `Bundle` e queira acessa-lo várias vezes. Apenas por boas práticas):

```
...
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null){
    Byte valor = bundle.getByte("valor");
} 
...
```

2) Recuperar diretamente do seu getIntent().getExtras():

```
...   
if(getIntent().hasExtra("valor")){
    Byte valor = getIntent().getByteExtra("valor", 0);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentei fazer uma implementacao similar hoje e para resolver, na segunda Activity eu fiz

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
bundle= intent.getExtras();
Byte valor = bundle.getByte("valor");
```

Aparentemente quando você não inicializa o bundle ele não consegue pegar os valores..